# Group a list of duplicate Objects without removing duplicate into a map

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects in an array. Each object has an email.

The array could have duplicate emails and I want to keep them.

I want to give a number let's say 4 and it should split the emails into groups of 4 emails into a map where the key is like group-1 ... and the value 4 unique emails in each key
in this case I will have a map of 5 keys

```
const emails=[{userId:'someuserid',email:'email1@gmail.com',password:'password1',recovery:'recovery1@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email1@gmail.com',password:'password1',recovery:'recovery1@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email10@gmail.com',password:'password10',recovery:'recovery10@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email10@gmail.com',password:'password10',recovery:'recovery10@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email2@gmail.com',password:'password2',recovery:'recovery2@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email2@gmail.com',password:'password2',recovery:'recovery2@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email3@gmail.com',password:'password3',recovery:'recovery3@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email3@gmail.com',password:'password3',recovery:'recovery3@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email4@gmail.com',password:'password4',recovery:'recovery4@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email4@gmail.com',password:'password4',recovery:'recovery4@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email5@gmail.com',password:'password5',recovery:'recovery5@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email5@gmail.com',password:'password5',recovery:'recovery5@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email6@gmail.com',password:'password6',recovery:'recovery6@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email6@gmail.com',password:'password6',recovery:'recovery6@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email7@gmail.com',password:'password7',recovery:'recovery7@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email7@gmail.com',password:'password7',recovery:'recovery7@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email8@gmail.com',password:'password8',recovery:'recovery8@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email8@gmail.com',password:'password8',recovery:'recovery8@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email9@gmail.com',password:'password9',recovery:'recovery9@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email9@gmail.com',password:'password9',recovery:'recovery9@gmail.com'}]

const groupsMap = new Map()
let sequence = 0
let profilePrefix = 'none'
let pivotPrefix = 0
const prefix = 'group'
const bucketSize = 4
for (let index = 0; index < emails.length; index++) {
  const currentEmail = emails[index]?.email
  const prevEmail = emails[index - 1]?.email
  if (prevEmail && currentEmail === prevEmail) {
    if (
      groupsMap.has(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`) &&
      groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).length < bucketSize &&
      groupsMap
        .get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`)
        .findIndex((email) => currentEmail === email.email) === -1
    ) {
      groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).push(emails[index])
      if (
        groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).length === bucketSize
      ) {
        pivotPrefix++
      }
    } else {
      if (pivotPrefix > 0) {
        const nextPivot = pivotPrefix++
        groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${nextPivot}`).push(emails[index])
      }
      sequence++
      profilePrefix = `${prefix}-${sequence}`
      groupsMap.set(profilePrefix, [emails[index]])
    }
  } else {
    if (groupsMap.has(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`)) {
      if (
        groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).length < bucketSize
      ) {
        groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).push(emails[index])
        if (
          groupsMap.get(`${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`).length ===
          bucketSize
        ) {
          pivotPrefix++
        }
      } else {
        sequence++
        groupsMap.set(`${prefix}-${sequence}`, [emails[index]])
      }
    } else {
      sequence++
      pivotPrefix = sequence
      profilePrefix = `${prefix}-${pivotPrefix}`
      groupsMap.set(profilePrefix, [emails[index]])
    }
  }
}

console.log(groupsMap)

// desired output below
Map(6) {
  'group-0' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email1@gmail.com',
      password: 'password1',
      recovery: 'recovery1@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email10@gmail.com',
      password: 'password10',
      recovery: 'recovery10@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email2@gmail.com',
      password: 'password2',
      recovery: 'recovery2@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email3@gmail.com',
      password: 'password3',
      recovery: 'recovery3@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  'group-1' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email1@gmail.com',
      password: 'password1',
      recovery: 'recovery1@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email10@gmail.com',
      password: 'password10',
      recovery: 'recovery10@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email2@gmail.com',
      password: 'password2',
      recovery: 'recovery2@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email3@gmail.com',
      password: 'password3',
      recovery: 'recovery3@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  'group-2' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email4@gmail.com',
      password: 'password4',
      recovery: 'recovery4@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email5@gmail.com',
      password: 'password5',
      recovery: 'recovery5@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email6@gmail.com',
      password: 'password6',
      recovery: 'recovery6@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email7@gmail.com',
      password: 'password7',
      recovery: 'recovery7@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  'group-3' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email4@gmail.com',
      password: 'password4',
      recovery: 'recovery4@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email5@gmail.com',
      password: 'password5',
      recovery: 'recovery5@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email6@gmail.com',
      password: 'password6',
      recovery: 'recovery6@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email7@gmail.com',
      password: 'password7',
      recovery: 'recovery7@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  'group-4' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email8@gmail.com',
      password: 'password8',
      recovery: 'recovery8@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email9@gmail.com',
      password: 'password9',
      recovery: 'recovery9@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  'group-5' => [
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email8@gmail.com',
      password: 'password8',
      recovery: 'recovery8@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      userId: 'someuserid',
      email: 'email9@gmail.com',
      password: 'password9',
      recovery: 'recovery9@gmail.com'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you please add you desired output sample as well.

Comment: @Nikkkshit It's all the way doooooooooooooown at the end of the codeblock - a map with example keys to values.

Comment: What are the specific problems?

Comment: So, you want 4 unique email groups right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the groups as "buckets", and find the next bucket to put the email in. If no buckets have available spots, create a new bucket with the email.

```js
const emails=[{userId:'someuserid',email:'email1@gmail.com',password:'password1',recovery:'recovery1@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email1@gmail.com',password:'password1',recovery:'recovery1@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email10@gmail.com',password:'password10',recovery:'recovery10@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email10@gmail.com',password:'password10',recovery:'recovery10@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email2@gmail.com',password:'password2',recovery:'recovery2@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email2@gmail.com',password:'password2',recovery:'recovery2@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email3@gmail.com',password:'password3',recovery:'recovery3@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email3@gmail.com',password:'password3',recovery:'recovery3@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email4@gmail.com',password:'password4',recovery:'recovery4@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email4@gmail.com',password:'password4',recovery:'recovery4@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email5@gmail.com',password:'password5',recovery:'recovery5@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email5@gmail.com',password:'password5',recovery:'recovery5@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email6@gmail.com',password:'password6',recovery:'recovery6@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email6@gmail.com',password:'password6',recovery:'recovery6@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email7@gmail.com',password:'password7',recovery:'recovery7@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email7@gmail.com',password:'password7',recovery:'recovery7@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email8@gmail.com',password:'password8',recovery:'recovery8@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email8@gmail.com',password:'password8',recovery:'recovery8@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email9@gmail.com',password:'password9',recovery:'recovery9@gmail.com'},{userId:'someuserid',email:'email9@gmail.com',password:'password9',recovery:'recovery9@gmail.com'}]

const buckets = [];

const bucketSize = 4;

emails.forEach((e) => {
    const bucketIndex = buckets
      .map((b, i) => [b, i]) // zip with index
      .filter(([b]) => b.length < bucketSize) // buckets that aren't full
      .find(([b]) => b.every((u) => u.email !== e.email)); // bucket with available spot

    if (bucketIndex === undefined) buckets.push([e]); // create new bucket
    else buckets[bucketIndex[1]].push(e); // push to existing bucket by index
});

// zip with keys and create map
const map = new Map(buckets.map((b, i) => [`group-${i}`, b]));

// Just for display - Maps aren't displayed properly in the output yet
console.log(Object.fromEntries(Array.from(map)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: seems like it's correct let me test it

Comment: seems correct , but the it should have exactly 5 keys each has 4 unique emails

Comment: @abdeljalilaitetaleb Your provided data makes this impossible. See the output of my code again. There are two buckets at the end - each with email8 and email9, so it's impossible for them to be in the same bucket without having duplicate emails.

Comment: yes you are right your solution is correct

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure But if you want group of unique emails than this will give you 4 object with unique emails.**

---

- First I am filtering array with unique values of email and than using `chunk` function, that takes two parameter one the array and second the size of array.
- The procedure of chunk function is as below, the only thing **missing here is key otherwise you are getting 4 email object of array in chunks.
- Take an empty array to push array chuncks
- check if we will have extra chunks or not;
- if array length's moudle with chunk size is not equal to zero that we have to count the number of rounds
- if array length's moudle with chunk size is zero than we just need to push array.splice(0,size) till the array size is not equals to zero
- if we have rounds , than we just need to push array till the rounds are not complete once its compelete we just need to add extra to result by arra.push(0,extra);
- In other words,push chunks in array till our array's length is not equal to extra and once array length is just as extra add remaining by arra.push(0,extra);

```js
const emails = [{
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email1@gmail.com',
    password: 'password1',
    recovery: 'recovery1@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email1@gmail.com',
    password: 'password1',
    recovery: 'recovery1@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email10@gmail.com',
    password: 'password10',
    recovery: 'recovery10@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email10@gmail.com',
    password: 'password10',
    recovery: 'recovery10@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email2@gmail.com',
    password: 'password2',
    recovery: 'recovery2@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email2@gmail.com',
    password: 'password2',
    recovery: 'recovery2@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email3@gmail.com',
    password: 'password3',
    recovery: 'recovery3@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email3@gmail.com',
    password: 'password3',
    recovery: 'recovery3@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email4@gmail.com',
    password: 'password4',
    recovery: 'recovery4@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email4@gmail.com',
    password: 'password4',
    recovery: 'recovery4@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email5@gmail.com',
    password: 'password5',
    recovery: 'recovery5@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email5@gmail.com',
    password: 'password5',
    recovery: 'recovery5@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email6@gmail.com',
    password: 'password6',
    recovery: 'recovery6@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email6@gmail.com',
    password: 'password6',
    recovery: 'recovery6@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email7@gmail.com',
    password: 'password7',
    recovery: 'recovery7@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email7@gmail.com',
    password: 'password7',
    recovery: 'recovery7@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email8@gmail.com',
    password: 'password8',
    recovery: 'recovery8@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email8@gmail.com',
    password: 'password8',
    recovery: 'recovery8@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email9@gmail.com',
    password: 'password9',
    recovery: 'recovery9@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    userId: 'someuserid',
    email: 'email9@gmail.com',
    password: 'password9',
    recovery: 'recovery9@gmail.com'
  }
];
let filterdResult = []; // to store unique email objects
// to filter emails object with unique email
let filterArray = emails.reduce((visitedEmailContainer, currentEmail) => {
  if (!visitedEmailContainer.includes(currentEmail.email)) {
    filterdResult.push(currentEmail);
    visitedEmailContainer.push(currentEmail.email);
    return visitedEmailContainer;
  }
  return visitedEmailContainer;
}, []);

function chunk(array, size) {
  /*
  - Take an empty array to push array chuncks
  - check if we will have extra chunks or not;
  - if array length's moudle with chunk size is not equal to zero that we have to count the number of rounds
  - if array length's moudle with chunk size is zero than we just need to push array.splice(0,size) till the array size is not equals to zero
  - if we have rounds , than we just need to push array till the rounds are not complete once its compelete we just need to add extra to result by arra.push(0,extra); 
  - In other words,push chunks in array till our array's length is not equal to extra and once array length is just as extra add remaining by arra.push(0,extra);
   */
  let result = [];
  let extra = array.length % size;
  if (extra == 0) {
    while (array.length !== 0) {
      result.push(array.splice(0, size));
    }
  } else if (extra) {
    while (array.length != extra) {
      result.push(array.splice(0, size));
    }
    result.push(array.splice(0, extra));
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
chunk(filterdResult, 4);
```

Comment: OP wants to *keep* duplicates, not remove them.

Comment: oh for my solution he can pass array directly

Comment: I think he wants group of 4 unique emails according to his question

Comment: the result should have 5 subarrays it only have 3 , i want to keep the duplicate in another subarray